# Enable HDMI output for AM3358 Debian 10.3 2020-04-06 4GB SD IoT (BeagleBone Black)

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot, debian-buster

I am trying to get my BeagleBone Black to post to my monitor, to be able to use it as a stand-alone PC.

This was possible with the image that the BeagleBone shipped with.

I have just installed a new image on my BeagleBone Black Rev C.

The new image is AM3358 Debian 10.3 2020-04-06 4GB SD IoT.

I am able to SSH to it using PuTTY, and this way I have succesfully performed some actions with it, like using wget to download files from Google Drive etc.

So it seems like the board is working well, and that the HDMI output is disabled somewhere.

I have copied the contents of the uEnv.txt-file below, to show that the lines regarding disabling of video are commented out:

```
#Docs: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:U-boot_partitioning_layout_2.0

uname_r=4.19.94-ti-r42
#uuid=
#dtb=

###U-Boot Overlays###
###Documentation: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#U-Boot_Overlays
###Master Enable
enable_uboot_overlays=1
###
###Overide capes with eeprom
#uboot_overlay_addr0=/lib/firmware/<file0>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr1=/lib/firmware/<file1>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr2=/lib/firmware/<file2>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr3=/lib/firmware/<file3>.dtbo
###
###Additional custom capes
#uboot_overlay_addr4=/lib/firmware/<file4>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr5=/lib/firmware/<file5>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr6=/lib/firmware/<file6>.dtbo
#uboot_overlay_addr7=/lib/firmware/<file7>.dtbo
###
###Custom Cape
#dtb_overlay=/lib/firmware/<file8>.dtbo
###
###Disable auto loading of virtual capes (emmc/video/wireless/adc)
#disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_video=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_audio=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_wireless=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_adc=1
###
###PRUSS OPTIONS
###pru_rproc (4.14.x-ti kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-14-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_rproc (4.19.x-ti kernel)
uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-19-TI-00A0.dtbo
###pru_uio (4.14.x-ti, 4.19.x-ti & mainline/bone kernel)
#uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-UIO-00A0.dtbo
###
###Cape Universal Enable
enable_uboot_cape_universal=1
###
###Debug: disable uboot autoload of Cape
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr0=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr1=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr2=1
#disable_uboot_overlay_addr3=1
###
###U-Boot fdt tweaks... (60000 = 384KB)
#uboot_fdt_buffer=0x60000
###U-Boot Overlays###

cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet

#In the event of edid real failures, uncomment this next line:

#cmdline=coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e

##enable Generic eMMC Flasher:
##make sure, these tools are installed: dosfstools rsync
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh
```

Furthermore, the contents of /opt/scripts/tools/version.sh

```
git:/opt/scripts/:[a335abcf87d2ef5fd96e7de83cdf3f0ff5a4da2b]
eeprom:[A335BNLT00C02128SBB11942]
model:[TI_AM335x_BeagleBone_Black]
dogtag:[BeagleBoard.org Debian Buster IoT Image 2020-04-06]
bootloader:[microSD-(push-button)]:[/dev/mmcblk0]:[U-Boot SPL 2019.04-00002-gc9b3922522 (Aug 24 2020 - 16:42:18 -0500)]:[location: dd MBR]
bootloader:[microSD-(push-button)]:[/dev/mmcblk0]:[U-Boot 2019.04-00002-gc9b3922522]:[location: dd MBR]
bootloader:[eMMC-(default)]:[/dev/mmcblk1]:[U-Boot SPL 2019.04-00002-g07d5700e21 (Mar 06 2020 - 11:24:55 -0600)]:[location: dd MBR]
bootloader:[eMMC-(default)]:[/dev/mmcblk1]:[U-Boot 2019.04-00002-g07d5700e21]:[location: dd MBR]
UBOOT: Booted Device-Tree:[am335x-boneblack-uboot-univ.dts]
UBOOT: Loaded Overlay:[AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-19-TI-00A0]
UBOOT: Loaded Overlay:[BB-ADC-00A0.bb.org-overlays]
UBOOT: Loaded Overlay:[BB-BONE-eMMC1-01-00A0.bb.org-overlays]
UBOOT: Loaded Overlay:[BB-HDMI-TDA998x-00A0.bb.org-overlays]
kernel:[4.19.94-ti-r42]
nodejs:[v10.24.0]
/boot/uEnv.txt Settings:
uboot_overlay_options:[enable_uboot_overlays=1]
uboot_overlay_options:[uboot_overlay_pru=/lib/firmware/AM335X-PRU-RPROC-4-19-TI-00A0.dtbo]
uboot_overlay_options:[enable_uboot_cape_universal=1]
pkg check: to individually upgrade run: [sudo apt install --only-upgrade <pkg>]
pkg:[bb-cape-overlays]:[4.14.20210821.0-0~buster+20210821]
pkg:[bb-customizations]:[1.20211215.2-0~buster+20220102]
pkg:[bb-usb-gadgets]:[1.20220112.3-0~buster+20220112]
pkg:[bb-wl18xx-firmware]:[1.20211222.2-0~buster+20211222]
pkg:[kmod]:[26-1]
pkg:[librobotcontrol]:[1.0.5-git20200715.0-0~buster+20200716]
pkg:[firmware-ti-connectivity]:[20190717-2rcnee1~buster+20200305]
groups:[debian : debian adm kmem dialout cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev users systemd-journal bluetooth netdev i2c gpio pwm eqep remoteproc admin spi iio docker tisdk weston-launch xenomai cloud9ide]
cmdline:[console=ttyO0,115200n8 bone_capemgr.uboot_capemgr_enabled=1 root=/dev/mmcblk1p1 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait coherent_pool=1M net.ifnames=0 lpj=1990656 rng_core.default_quality=100 quiet video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e]
dmesg | grep remote
[   43.365021] remoteproc remoteproc0: wkup_m3 is available
[   43.467266] remoteproc remoteproc0: powering up wkup_m3
[   43.467297] remoteproc remoteproc0: Booting fw image am335x-pm-firmware.elf, size 217168
[   43.474100] remoteproc remoteproc0: remote processor wkup_m3 is now up
[   45.923727] remoteproc remoteproc1: 4a334000.pru is available
[   45.927100] remoteproc remoteproc2: 4a338000.pru is available
dmesg | grep pru
[   45.923727] remoteproc remoteproc1: 4a334000.pru is available
[   45.923942] pru-rproc 4a334000.pru: PRU rproc node pru@4a334000 probed successfully
[   45.927100] remoteproc remoteproc2: 4a338000.pru is available
[   45.927243] pru-rproc 4a338000.pru: PRU rproc node pru@4a338000 probed successfully
dmesg | grep pinctrl-single
[    0.949255] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: 142 pins, size 568
[    1.475029] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin PIN108 already requested by ocp:A15_pinmux; cannot claim for 0-0070
[    1.485668] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin-108 (0-0070) status -22
[    1.492351] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: could not request pin 108 (PIN108) from group nxp_hdmi_bonelt_pins  on device pinctrl-single
dmesg | grep gpio-of-helper
[    0.962575] gpio-of-helper ocp:cape-universal: ready
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, following a solution found [here](https://forum.beagleboard.org/t/bb-black-not-displaying-on-reboot/30823).

The solution was to run a kernel update:

```
sudo /opt/scripts/tools/update_kernel.sh
```

So the real hero here is RobertCNelson who provided that answer.